# Running `$log = new \Application\Log();` calls \Application\Log::log(); for some reason

Tags: php, constructor

I have a weird problem: I extended Zend_Log with a class called `\Application\Log` (it just contains a `log` method that overload's `Zend_Log`'s method of the same name). But when I run `$log = new \Application\Log();`, php tries to run the `log` method for some reason, as if it's a php4-style constructor. What can I do to get around this?

Comment: As of PHP 5.3.3, methods with the same name as the last element of a namespaced class name will no longer be treated as constructor. This change doesn't affect non-namespaced classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify a blank constructor in the child class.

Comment: Is this hacky solution really the best practice here?

Comment: To be honest, it was the first idea to come up in my head. I didn't even waited it work. :)